# Implement the 'pull down to refresh' technology on mobile view

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

The *pull down to refresh* thing is becoming a growing trend on mobile apps/sites. In case you don't know what I am talking about, here is an example:

[image: Example screen captures]

<sub>[(image source)](http://dailyiphoneblog.com/2011/08/04/gmail-for-iphone-gets-a-refresh-with-pull-to-refresh-and-more/)</sub>

**Note:** the image doesn't reflect 100% how this feature really is, the "Pull down to refresh" is hidden all the time and only becomes visible when you start scrolling beyond the limits of the page.

This could be very handy to have in the mobile view since we don't have live refresh thing going on (and good thing we don't, it could quickly drain the resources of users without unlimited data transfer plans).

I believe in couple of years, there will be no mobile app/site without this intuitive feature.

They might want to check if that thing is patented first to avoid getting in trouble.

Comment: Better AskPatents if there's prior art on this

Comment: Sounds like something Safari should implement...

Comment: I would vote against this if it would need a fixed header, like shown in the example screenshots, and like present in many apps. But I guess it can be implemented without that, though that would require one to scroll to top first, before it can be activated. I would not use it; my browser's refresh is just fine to me, and when I've scrolled to the top so is clicking the logo. (As an aside, I've actually seen apps that used to do it like this, but now have a simple refresh button, which just takes a single touch. Gmail on Android doesn't have it either. More of an iOS thing, I feel.)

Comment: @Arjan there is no fixed header, as I said in my _note:_ it is hidden all the time until you start scrolling beyond the limits of the page

Comment: Surely there's a fixed header in your example screenshot, and the "pull down" part is below that. And I've not yet seen any app or web page *without* such fixed header that implemented such reload-when-scrolled-too-far. But indeed, I guess it's not a requirement to implement it. (Though maybe it is: I can imagine that some browsers "steal" the scrolled-too-far event of the main viewport to, for example, show their location bar or other hidden things. I don't know. I would not want to mess with that by using some fake 0 or 1 pixel header.)